# phpmyadmin stopped working after installing wamp server 2

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

hi had a working phpmyadmin which stopped working when i installed a new version of wamp 2 for windows 32bit.

Now i have mysqlBuddy appearing in my localhost homepage and it mysqlBuddy works but when i click on phpmyadmin it doesn't work. The error i am getting is *Access Denied*. please read below error.

```
> Error
>     
>         MySQL said: Documentation Cannot connect: invalid settings.
> phpMyAdmin tried to
> 
>  connect to the MySQL server, and the
> server rejected the connection.  You
> should check the host, username and
> password in your configuration and
> make  sure that they correspond to the
> information given by the 
> administrator of the MySQL server.
```

i have checked the config.inc.php file which is under the phpmyadmin folder to see the config settings and they are all ok

```
/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

i do not know how else i can fix this. ?

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli'; aren't u using mysql instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to cover all bases - Have you tried restarting WAMP server after changing PHPMyAdmin's configuration?

If you still cannot connect, try resetting your MySQL root password by following the instructions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).